# Is making a colpitts of 400+ MHz on a breadboard practical?

Tags: rf

I have been designing a colpitts but it stops working above 300 kHz. Is this due to parasitics in the breadboard? I am using a common emmitter amplifier style colpitts.

Comment: We don't know how you are designing it, but anything 400+ MHz and breadboard does not sound very practical.

Comment: My personal upper limit for those white breadboards is 10MHz, at which point you're already either designing around or living with the constraints of the board.  If your goal is to build a 400MHz oscillator **at all** then don't use a breadboard.  If your goal is to build a 400MHz oscillator **on a breadboard** then -- have fun.  If you have **some other goal** then **edit your question** to tell us what you're **really** trying to accomplish, what problems you're running into, and what you need solved.  "How would I prototype a 400MHz oscillator" could be a fair question, for instance.

Comment: It is possible, but practicality is in the eye of the beholder. Knock yourself out: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZSS2ajxhiQBXX-hLFPNWD_GAECi6BOZC

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely you will be able to get a Colpitts oscillator oscillating at 400 MHz on a solderless breadboard. The parasitic capacitances and inductances will almost certainly limit the maximum oscillation frequency to below 400 MHz.

It *is* possible to get an 11 MHz crystal oscillator to work on solderless breadboard. However, I cannot tell you where, in between 11 MHz and 400 MHz, things will stop working.

I think you *should* be able to get an oscillator using discrete caps and inductor well above 300 kHz on a solderless breadboard. However, you should use as short jumpers as possible, and caps and coil with low ESR.